# clicking on hyperlink need to display a edit form in html

Tags: javascript, html

i am displaying the data in table format when i click on id need to display the edit form on the same page without refreshing but when i click on user id it is displaying the form but when i click on second id it is closing the form.

If i click on first it should open the form and if i click on same id then only it should close if not it should be displayed.

If i click on second id then the edit form related to that id it should be displayed.

Here is the code

```html
<table  class="table table-striped" >
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>User Ids</th>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Email</th>
           <th>Phone</th>
           <th>User Role</th>
           <th>Status</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td><a href="#" onclick="toggler('myContent');">746</a></td>
           <td>Admin</td>
           <td>admin@gmail.com</td>
           <td>9989099890</td>
           <td>Admin</td>
           <td><i class="fa fa-check" title="Approved"></i></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><a href="#" onclick="toggler('myContent');">747</a></td>
           <td>Doctor</td>
           <td>doctor@gmail.com</td>
           <td>9999999999</td>
           <td>Doctor</td>
           <td><i class="fa fa-check" title="Approved"></i></td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<div id="myContent" class='hiddens'>
   <form action="#">
       <div class="">
           <div class="col-md-6">
               <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="first-name">First Name:</label>
               <input type="text" id="first-name" class="form-control validate">
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6">
               <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="last-name">Last Name:</label>
               <input type="text" id="last-name" class="form-control validate">
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6">
               <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="email">Email:</label>
               <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control validate">
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6">
               <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="phone-number">Phone Number:</label>
               <input type="text" id="phone-number" class="form-control validate">
           </div>
       </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function toggler(divId) {
    $("#" + divId).toggle();
}
```

CSS:

```css
.hiddens {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: *"then the edit form related to that id it should be displayed"* - You only have one form with one id...

Comment: use `$('#DivId').removeClass('hiddens');`

Comment: @David the data will be dynamic here i have posted sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this one.

```js
var oldID = ''
function toggler(divId,pageID) {
if($("#" + divId ).hasClass( "hiddens") || pageID != oldID)
$("#" + divId).removeClass('hiddens');
else
$("#" + divId).addClass('hiddens');

oldID = pageID;
}
```

```css
.hiddens {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table  class="table table-striped" >
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>User Ids</th>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Email</th>
           <th>Phone</th>
           <th>User Role</th>
           <th>Status</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td><a href="#" onclick="toggler('myContent',746);">746</a></td>
           <td>Admin</td>
           <td>admin@gmail.com</td>
           <td>9989099890</td>
           <td>Admin</td>
           <td><i class="fa fa-check" title="Approved"></i></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><a href="#" onclick="toggler('myContent',747);">747</a></td>
           <td>Doctor</td>
           <td>doctor@gmail.com</td>
           <td>9999999999</td>
           <td>Doctor</td>
           <td><i class="fa fa-check" title="Approved"></i></td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<div id="myContent" class='hiddens'>
   <form action="#">
       <div class="">
           <div class="col-md-6">
               <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="first-name">First Name:</label>
               <input type="text" id="first-name" class="form-control validate">
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6">
               <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="last-name">Last Name:</label>
               <input type="text" id="last-name" class="form-control validate">
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6">
               <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="email">Email:</label>
               <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control validate">
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6">
               <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="phone-number">Phone Number:</label>
               <input type="text" id="phone-number" class="form-control validate">
           </div>
       </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: If the data is dynamic then how can we pass the Id on onclick

Comment: you can pass dynamic value in the place of static value. like replace 742 with id. something like that